# jQuery Bootstrap dialog $backdrop is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-dialog

I'm using Bootstrap dialog [link](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) in my application. I have included the dependencies in the head section of the html

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/bootstrap-paginator.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/bootstrap-dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm getting the error

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of undefined
```

in the line

```
  $backdrop.css('z-index', zIndexBackdrop + (dialogCount - 1) * 20);
```

in *bootstrap-dialog.js* where $`backdrop` is `null`.

This is the code i have written

```
 callback.prototype.success = function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus){
         showDialog("Title",
                    "Message",
                    BootstrapDialog.TYPE_SUCCESS);

     }


     function showDialog(title,msg,type){
         BootstrapDialog.show({
                title: title,
                message: msg,
                type : type,
                buttons: [{
                    label: 'OK',
                    action: function(dialog) {
                         dialog.close();
                    }
                }]
            });
     }
```

I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Can you make fiddle for this?

Comment: why dont u add a class instead of writing a css..??

Comment: I'm trying to create a fiddle. @AminKodaganur That's from bootstrap dialog.js, not mine

Comment: there is something `cssClass` property in above mentioned link see it

Comment: In the source of bootstrap-dialog, are you able to debug and confirm `initModalStuff` is hit? This appears to be the point at which `setModal` is called and ensures `getModal` returns a value which in your case is returning undefined.

Comment: @PhilCooper Yes, it executes `initModalStuff`. The problem is with  while executing `updateZIndex()`

Comment: I got this fixed. The problem was with Bootstrap version, it was in major version 2. Upgrading to Bootstrap 3 version fixed it. Thanks for your time and help

Comment: @Keerthivasan good, I'd put that as an answer.

Comment: @PhilCooper Done, the $backdrop becoming null actually deviates the problem. Thank you Phil for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this fixed. The problem was with Bootstrap js version, it was in major version 2. Upgrading to `Bootstrap 3` version fixed it.